# How can I use an enum with a switch case in Java?

Tags: java, android, enums, switch-statement

Previously, I was saving the keys inside `SharedPreferencesManager` class using this way

```
public static final int KEY_COUNTRY_ID = 5,
     KEY_COUNTRY_NAME = 10,
     KEY_CURRENCY_ID = 15,
     KEY_CURRENCY_NAME = 20;
```

I decided to use an enum to store the keys because I think it is a better way than the old way, Here is what I tried.

**SharedPreferencesManager.java**

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private static void initializeSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null)
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static void initializeEditor() {
        if (editor == null)
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public static void setValue(Context context, String key, int value) {
        initializeSharedPreferences(context);
        initializeEditor();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getIntegerValue(Context context, String key) {
        initializeSharedPreferences(context);
        switch (key) {
            case Keys.COUNTRY_ID.name():
            case Keys.CURRENCY_ID.name():
                return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 5);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public enum Keys {
        COUNTRY_ID,
        COUNTRY_NAME,
        CURRENCY_ID,
        CURRENCY_NAME
    }

}
```

**The error**

```
Constant expression required
```

The red lines under `case Keys.COUNTRY_ID.name(): and case Keys.CURRENCY_ID.name():`

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You would need to switch on an instance of `Keys` rather than a string.

Comment: As the compiler tells you, you need to use a constant String expression if you use `switch(aStringVariable)`. The correct way to do this is to convert the `String` value to an enum constant and then use `switch` on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, you need to use a constant String expression if you use `switch(aStringVariable)`. The correct way to do this is to convert the `String` value to an enum constant and then use switch on that.

Convert the String to an enum instant using

```
Keys keyConstant = Keys.valueOf(key); //argument of "COUNTRY_ID" returns Keys.COUNTRY_ID
```

This looks up an enum constant by that name (matching the `name()`).
Then use it in the switch:

```
switch(keyConstant) {
  case COUNTRY_ID: ...
}
```

Comment: It's working, Thank you. Do you think I took the right decision by leaving the old method and using the new method?

Comment: @luq891 yes. From what I see, you were using the `public static final` fields as an enum. You can even assign numeric values to an enum constant in case you need to keep that functionality.